# Inf-convolution of norm 1 and norm 2 square

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

The inf-convolution of the functions $f$ and $g$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is
$$
h(x)=\inf _{y \in \mathbb{R}^n} f(y)+g(x-y) .
$$
We can prove that if $f,g$ are convex functions, then $h$ is convex.

If $f(t) = \lVert t \rVert_1$, and $g(t) = \frac{1}{2}\lVert t \rVert_2^2$, how can we compute $h$?

*My attempt*: I try to calculate the derivative but
$$
f(y) = \lVert y \rVert_1 =\sum_{i=1}^{n} |y_i|.
$$
That isn't differentiable at $0$.

Thank you for your help

Comment: This question is not for this forum. You may want to try https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you mean by $\Vert t\Vert_1$ and $\Vert t\Vert_2$?

Comment: Solve first in 1d where it is elementary and then the nd follows since $f(y)=\sum_i f_i(y_i)$.

Comment: I mean that 
if $y=(y_1;y_2;....y_n)$, then $\lVert y \rVert_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |y_i|$ and $\lVert y\rVert_2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2+...y_n^2}$